# How to use AudioControl with Phonegap?

Tags: java, javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I tried looking for a plugin, but couldn't find one, so I tried making my own. I want to turn silent mode on with a JavaScript command, but I get undefined method on getSystemService. I think there might be something wrong with my imports. Please help.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager; 

public class AudioControl extends CordovaPlugin {
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if (action.equals("echo")) {

        AudioManager audiomanage = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audiomanage.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

        String message = args.getString(0); 
        this.echo(message, callbackContext);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you pass `echo` as the action? Also do you have the permissions in you `res/xml/config.xml` right? And the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Yes to all three. I get the error in eclipse:
The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type AudioControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something I can think of is that the context is not right. Try this:

```
cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)
```

What version of PhoneGap / Cordova are you using?

Exluded issues:

- `echo` as action is correct
- `/res/xml/config.xml` the settings are correct
- `/AndroidMenifest.xml` has the correct settings